# Search and select multiples with where linq/lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I currently have the following code:

```
var FirstNameList = db.Clients.Include(x => x.FirstNames).Include(x => x.Addresses).SelectMany(a => a.FirstNames).Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Trim() == "Max".ToLower().Trim()).ToList();
```

I have a navigation property of FirstNames and Addresses which I which to include in the result.

I use the SelectMany Statement because it, for me, is the only one which works. Kind of. It returns all the FirstNames where the Name equals Max.

What I would like it to do is return all the Clients who have the property Name equals Max from the table FirstNames.

the other way I thought about doing this was to take all the ID's returned from FirstNameList and then returning the Clients by querying the data against the FirstNameList but I would be then querying the database twice, which seems inefficient.

My question is is it possible, and how would I go about querying the database to return my Clients, if it was?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you trying to get FirstName and Address for all users with name Max? Your question is not completely clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should give you what you're looking for. You can look within each client's FirstNames and see if any of them are named "max". (In this case, since "max" is a constant you're typing in, I removed the ToLower().Trim() from it)

```
var clientsNamedMax = db.Clients.Include(x => x.FirstNames).Include(x => x.Addresses).Where(x => x.FirstNames.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower().Trim() == "max")).ToList();
```